# Local Notification- Actions are not showing up with alert - iOS 11

Tags: swift, notifications

I have implemented local notification using UserNotifications framework and seting notification actions in the completion block of

`UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization`

But sometime categories are not getting set after code execution. I checked it using

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationCategories {}
```

This is not heppening everytime. Sometime when I delete and reinstalled the app or re-run the app it starts working.

Do I should set categories on main thread or what could be the reason of this wired case?

Answer (score 0):

For me, the reason why it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't is the simulator I run it on. Some simulators don't have 3D touch and the actions won't show up.